# $x,y,z>0$, prove:$\frac{x}{y+z+\sqrt[4]\frac{y^4+z^4}{2}}+\frac{y}{z+x+\sqrt[4]\frac{z^4+x^4}{2}}+\frac{z}{x+y+\sqrt[4]\frac{x^4+y^4}{2}}\geq1$

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

If $x,y,z>0$, prove:$$ \frac{x}{y+z+\sqrt[4]\frac{y^4+z^4}{2}}+\frac{y}{z+x+\sqrt[4]\frac{z^4+x^4}{2}}+\frac{z}{x+y+\sqrt[4]\frac{x^4+y^4}{2}}\geq1$$ I tried to use classical ineqalities such as AM-GM or QM-GM to prove this inequality. I have noticed equality holds when $x=y=z$.
The next part of the question is asking if this inequality can be generalized.

> Another inequality with same nature.If $x,y,z>0$, prove or disprove:$$ \frac{x}{y+z+\sqrt[6]\frac{y^6+z^6}{2}}+\frac{y}{z+x+\sqrt[6]\frac{z^6+x^6}{2}}+\frac{z}{x+y+\sqrt[6]\frac{x^6+y^6}{2}}\geq1$$
>   These questions are proposed from R. Shahbazov and J. Hajimir to RMM.

Comment: Why did you add the upper bound statement that is incorrect? You can find a contradiction for $\le \frac{4}{3}$ part easily by letting $x=1$ and letting $y=z=0.01$ (small number).

Comment: I made a mistake, I removed it.

Comment: A remark for the second inequality: Note that (assuming $x\le y\le z$) $$LHS\geq \frac{x}{y+2 z}+\frac{z}{x+2 y}+\frac{y}{x+2 z}.$$ The last expression has a global minimum of about $0.97$. As a bonus however, this bound works for any exponent

Comment: How did ou come up withthe lower bound.

Comment: @Keon It is because $$\sqrt[n]{\frac{x^n+y^n}2}\le\max(x,y)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4+y^4}{2}}\leq\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}$$ it's just $(x-y)^4\geq0,$ it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{z}{x+y+\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}}\geq1$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{z(x+y-\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2})}{3xy}\geq1$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z-xyz)\geq\sum_{cyc}z^2\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^2y+x^2z}{2}-xyz\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}z^2\left(\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}-\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{3z^2(x-y)^2}{2\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}+x+y}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\left(1-\frac{3z}{2\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}+x+y}\right)\geq0.$$
Now, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $$y^2(x-z)^2\geq x^2(y-z)^2,$$ $$2\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}\geq2x-z,$$ $$2\sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2}\geq2y-z,$$ $$1-\frac{3y}{2\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}+x+z}\geq1-\frac{3y}{2x-z+x+z}\geq0$$ and 
$$y^2\sum_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\left(1-\frac{3z}{2\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}+x+y}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq y\cdot y^2(x-z)^2\left(1-\tfrac{3y}{2\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}+x+z}\right)+ x\cdot y^2(y-z)^2\left(1-\tfrac{3x}{2\sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2}+y+z}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq y\cdot x^2(y-z)^2\left(1-\tfrac{3y}{3x-z+x+z}\right)+ x\cdot y^2(y-z)^2\left(1-\tfrac{3x}{2y-z+y+z}\right)=$$
$$=xy(y-z)^2\left(x\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)+y\left(1-\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)=0$$ and we are done!

Comment: Do you mean $z$ at the top for $1-\frac{3y}{2\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}+x+z}\geq1-\frac{3y}{2x-z+x+z}\geq0$ instead? I know it is true for $y$ as well.

Comment: @Xiaohai Zhang No, it's $y$. With $z$ it's $1-\frac{3z}{2\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}+x+y}.$

Comment: Then where is the $z$ item in the following $y^2\sum_{cyc}$ expansion?

Comment: @Xiaohai Zhang this term is non-negative.

Comment: That is exactly why I was suggesting you to change the inequality about $y$ to be of $z$ to show it is nonnegative.

Comment: @Xiaohai Zhang But it's obvious that $1-\frac{3z}{2\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}+x+y}\geq0.$ No?

Comment: You never needed or used $1-\frac{3y}{2\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}+x+z}\geq1-\frac{3y}{2x-z+x+z}\geq0$.

Comment: @Xiaohai Zhang We need it for using $y^2(x-z)^2\geq x^2(y-z)^2.$